# Freelancer - Where is the New York G6 jump hole?

Tags: freelancer

I've gone over this area several times and I can't seem to find it. It should be located where my ship is displayed on the map.

Am I in the wrong location?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be due north of the "New York -> Texas" jump gate, right on the FG6 line (so a little bit southwest of where you're chilling on your screenshot). This one shows up as "Unknown Object" on your sensors.

But if you still can't find it, it's possible that it doesn't exist until you've reached a much later point in the storyline. I believe one of the jump holes in New York doesn't appear until you need it to sneak around the system. I had thought it was the one you've found at EF7 (close to Buffalo Station), but maybe I'm wrong. I haven't been able to find any guides that are clear on this point. Have you been able to traverse the EF7 jump hole you found? I had also thought it would spit you out right at the other one (this is an in-system jump hole), but maybe it's not traversable yet.

Comment: I found the other three jump holes; the two by the Buffalo base and the one by Rochester base. Just not this one.

Comment: I remember finding one that I shouldn't have and it said "Access Denied." even though it's a natural occurrence :\

Answer (score -1):

This New York G6 jump hole is 5000K below your ship.

Comment: Edited. Ini shows -5000